# Domain & subdomain url

Tags: dns, subdomain, multilingual

I build multilingual site and decided to use following scheme for different languages:
de.mydomain.com
cz.mydomain.com
and so on.

But I have a question about main site, which is in English. Should I use:
A) mydomain.com
B) www.mydomain.com

Could version A cause any problems and shouldn't be used? Or is it not important which type I chose? I see that many international sites with lang.domain.com urls use www on the main site...

Answer (score 1):

Have www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com be the same site, please please please.

[Your browser indicates](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/content-negotiation.html) what language you wish to display content in — you should use this method, but also provide a language-changing link somewhere on the landing page, in addition to being nice (like Wikipedia) and letting folks go directly to de.mydomain.com, cz.mydomain,com, eo.mydomain.com, etc.

Comment: Yeah, www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com is the same site, in English. I know how to check language (cookies, user settings, browser etc), but wanted to know if using www on main site is some kind of standard or it doesn't matter.

Comment: Generally www.foo.bar and foo.bar point at the same server.  It's a rare thing when it doesn't and can be a bit of a pain.  I don't like making the extra four keystrokes … but some folks feel as if it's not a web site unless you do type "www." in front of it.  An example of a host that requires the www. is kcscout.net.  With the www. you get traffic information for Kansas City.  Without … you either get nothing (now) or (in the past) a login page which appears to lead you to their internal CMS.